# Delay on active state for touch devices

Tags: mobile, touchstart

I'm using the following code to allow ":active" state for touchevents..

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);
```

It works perfect, but is there a way to put a short delay on this if you are scrolling?  I am trying to avoid the items in the list from being ":active" if you are just scrolling.  For example.. Think of the "Contacts" list on your phone.  If you scroll, the name/item does not trigger the ":active" style until you specifically press on the item.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, i think this is what you need.

http://brice.lechatellier.com/code-design/enable-active-state-on-touch-devices-with-jquery-zepto/